# What happens when the source of light and distance between the slits is changed in Young's Double slit experiment

Tags: optics

What happens when the distance between the slit and the source of light is changed in Young's Double slit experiment.

Comment: I think that you ought to suggest what you think are the answers to your questions?

Comment: All capital nicks look bad, I suggest to change simply to "Mohd Shakib".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Collimated light**

It is said that to get the best results for sharp fringes one has to use a pointlike source of monochromatic light. The more precise requirement is that the light has to be a [collimated beam](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collimated_light), means the beam has to be of equal thickness over a long distance.

[image: from Wikipedia]

A pinhole in front of any diffraction experiment with edges, slit or double slits will do the same as a long distance of a more extended source as long as it uses the part of the light that has nearly parallel beam components.

**Different distance from the source**

As long as the light that exposure the slits is collimated the intensity distribution behind the slits will be sharp. So a source with a collimated beam could be moved towards the slits or away from the slits, the intensity distribution will not changes in theory. In praxis moving the source far away will decrease the intensity of the light due to air dust and do to the imperfect collimating, the beam will be broader aand broader at long distances.

Young's equation for the calculation of the wavelength of the used monocromaticc light ([according to this page](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/light/u12l3d)) does not contain a parameter for the distance from the source to the screen:

**λ = y • d / (m • L)**

- Slit Separation (d)
- Distance from Slits to Screen (L)
- Distance from peak(0) to peak(m) (y)
- Order value (m)